# Aggregating multiple DBs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have several SQL DBs in Azure. All have the same structure. Each DB represents a different location. What would be the best practice to aggreate the data of all locations? The goal would be to be able to answer queries like „How much material of type X was used in time range x to y accross all locations?“ or „Give me the location that produces the highest outcome?“

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Azure SQL database Elastic pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool).

Add all of your databases to the Elastic pool.

With [Elastic query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview) can help you aggreate the data of all locations in Azure.

The elastic query feature (in preview) enables you to run a Transact-SQL query that spans multiple databases in Azure SQL Database. It allows you to perform cross-database queries to access remote tables, and to connect Microsoft and third-party tools (Excel, Power BI, Tableau, etc.) to query across data tiers with multiple databases. Using this feature, you can scale out queries to large data tiers in SQL Database and visualize the results in business intelligence (BI) reports.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would it be possible to include the site information in the query result? E.g. each DB represents a shop site and I would like to query the sum of all sold articles per shop site.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation in this scenario is to create a new database which we will name as the "hub" database and it will consolidate the information of all location databases which we will name as "member" databases. Use [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) to synchronize each member database to the hub database. Use T-SQL and Power BI against the hub database to answer all your questions involving all locations.

I participated on a project of a Mexican retail store with 72 stores across Mexico they created a hub database to consolidate sales at the end of the day, and use Power BI to show consolidated sales to stakeholders.

Comment: Sounds also good, but I would like to avoid additional implementation effort.